# EDSunriseSet time in location's TimeZone

Tags: ios, c, datetime, time, timezone

Is it possible to display sunset and sunrise times in the location's timezone using EDSunriseSet?

I'm in GMT+1, and both `[edSunriseSet sunrise]` and when calculating from the `localSunset` date components give time in my own local timezone.

Comment: see [ios-sunrise-sunset-corelocation](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/09/ios-sunrise-sunset-corelocation/)

Comment: Read the question. I don't need the time in my own local timezone, but in location's timezone.